# How can I make my Drag Target follow when my Draggable widget moves?

Tags: flutter, dart, draggable

I want my Drag target to follow the draggable widget when it moves, really appreciate if you could help!

Before Drag

[image]

After Drag

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what actually happens?

Comment: really just a beginner in flutter, I tried calling a positioned widget with dragtarget in setstate of the draggable.